# Numerical Integration of $\int^{t_i}_{t_i-\Delta t}\frac{e^{-\frac{a}{t_n-\tau}}}{\sqrt{t_n-\tau}}d\tau $ for heat conduction problem

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I am looking for a quadrature method to accurately evaluate the integral:

$$I=\int^{t_i}_{t_i-\Delta t}\frac{e^{-\frac{a}{t_n-\tau}}}{\sqrt{t_n-\tau}}d\tau $$

Where $a$ is a positive constant of the order $10^{-7}$, $\Delta t=5.0\times10^{-8}$ and $0\leq t_i\leq t_n\leq1.0\times10^{-5}$.

I have tried trapezoidal and simpsons quadrature and both are sufficiently accurate for larger $t_i ,t_n$ however they are highly inaccurate for smaller $t$ most likely due to the singularity at $t_i=t_n$. I am looking for a quadrature method that can give accurate results for small timescales.

For anyone interested this integral arises from a problem of heat conduction in a solid, $t_n , t_i$ are discrete time measurements.